# Using rabbitmq_user module with multiple permissions

Tags: ansible

I'm working on a RabbitMQ Ansible role and I have to write the task dedicated to users creation and configuration.

I defined the following variable in my playbook:

```
vars:  
  - rabbitmq_resources:
      - type_resource: "vhost"
        name: "/test"
        node: "rabbit@host1ansible"
      - type_resource: "vhost"
        name: "/other"
        node: "rabbit@host1ansible"
      - type_resource: "user"
        name: "rabbitmqadmin"
        password: "rabbitmqadmin"
        permissions:
          - vhost: "/test"
            configure_priv: ".*"
            read_priv: ".*"
            write_priv: ".*"
          - vhost: "/other"
            configure_priv: ".*"
            read_priv: ".*"
            write_priv: ".*"
        tags: "administrator"
        state: present
```

Then I want to write the task code dedicated to user processing:

```
- name: Creating RabbitMQ users
  rabbitmq_user:
    name: "{{ item.name|mandatory }}"
    permissions:
      vhost: "{{ item.value.vhost }}"
      configure_priv: "{{ item.value.configure_priv }}"
      read_priv: "{{ item.value.read_priv }}"
      write_priv: "{{ item.value.write_priv }}"
    tags: "{{ item.tags }}"
    state: present
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ rabbitmq_resources }}"
    - type_resource
    - permissions
  when: item.type_resource == "user"
```

The syntax above generates a message "subelements lookup expects a list of two or three items, the optional third item must be a dict with flags skip_missing".

I tested various loop syntaxes (with_items, with_subelements, with_dict) but I'm still unable to find the right one.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You approach isn't correct. You need to select only users from your dict and loop over it:

```
- name: Creating RabbitMQ users
  rabbitmq_user:
    name: "{{ item.name | mandatory }}"
    permissions: "{{ item.permissions | default(omit) }}"
    tags: "{{ item.tags | default(omit) }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - "{{ rabbitmq_resources | selectattr('type_resource','equalto','user') | list }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I decided to replace the permissions list by a JSON array:
`permissions: [{"vhost": "/test","configure_priv": ".*","read_priv": ".*","write_priv": ".*"},
              {"vhost": "/other","configure_priv": ".*","read_priv": ".*","write_priv": ".*"}]`

The task code is now:
`- name: Creating RabbitMQ users
      rabbitmq_user:
      name: "{{ item.name|mandatory }}"
      permissions: "{{ item.permissions }}"
      tags: "{{ item.tags }}"
      state: present
  with_items: "{{ rabbitmq_resources }}"
  when: item.type_resource == "user"`

and it works fine (default values code not included).

Dan

Comment: What you call _JSON array_ is the same list, as in OP, just written in other form.